# Flutter - BottomNavigationBar mais de três itens em branco

Tags: dart

Quando eu adiciono mais de 3 itens no componente (BottomNavigationBar), esta deixando em branco os meus itens.

[image: print1]

[image: print2]

Comment: poste mais delates sobre sua pergunta tipo, trechos de códio, mensagens de erro, etc...

Comment: Obrigado Stephen, próxima coloco mais informação :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como @HansMuller respondeu no post:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13642

> When more than 3 BottomNavigationBar items are provided the type, if unspecified, changes to BottomNavigationBarType.shifting

Quando temos mais de 3 itens no BottomNavigationBar, se não especificado, ele altera o tipo para BottomNavigationBarType.shifting.

> When the BottomNavigationBar's type is BottomNavigationBarType.shifting the items text and icons are rendered in white...

Quando o tipo do BottomNavigationBar é **shifting** os itens de texto e ícones são renderizados em branco...

Para resolver esse problema, basta apenas definir o tipo para **fixed**.

```dart
new BottomNavigationBar(
  type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
  items: [...],
);
```